# HTML snippets in sublime doesn't show unless an < precedes

Tags: html, css, editor, sublimetext3

I have this issue when I use HTML snippets in sublime.

When I start writting the snippet with a `<`, for example `<m-templa...`, a list of possible snippets will show up as normal. But when I hit TAB/ENTER the snippet shows but with a `<` at the beggining.

But When I write it without the `<` nothing appears, but sublime detects the snippet anyway when I write it completely and press TAB. Doing this

Is there a way for sublime to get rid of writting the `<` when I write html snippets or to tell sublime to not put the `<` for my own snippets?

**[EDIT]** I solved it. It was a bad installation of the package...

Comment: where are your `<m-templa` snippets coming from? a third party package you have installed? you could be running into this bug: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1281

Comment: Yeah, they come for a third party package called `materialize-snippets` or something like that. But this also happens with my owns snippets. I dont think it's that bug because in my case its not necesarily to write the`<` before I start tipping the snippet. I could simply type the entire snippet name and hit TAB and the snippet appears. But this package I installed have snippets names very difficult tu remember. So I'm trying to fix this because I want the dropdown meny for the snippets (or at least tell subime to get rid of the `<` when I write with it).